# Hazelcast custom timeout for operations

Tags: java, caching, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am using **"hazelcast.operation.call.timeout.millis = 100"** configuration to timeout hazelcast operations.

But at the startup of the hazelcast some of the map size operation are getting timeout because of this configuration. I just only want to timeout the operations after the map load which are basically map get operations. Is there any way to add custom operation timeout for those map.get() operations ?

Is there any other way to get this done ???

```
com.hazelcast.core.OperationTimeoutException: HDMapSizeOperation got rejected before execution due to not starting within the operation-call-timeout of: 100ms. Current time: 2017-05-15 11:41:47.503. Start time: 2017-05-15 11:41:44.189. Total elapsed time: 3314 ms. Invocation{op=com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.HDMapSizeOperation{serviceName='hz:impl:mapService', identityHash=1941379381, partitionId=0, replicaIndex=0, callId=-24461, invocationTime=1494828707296 (2017-05-15 11:41:47.296), waitTimeout=-1, callTimeout=100, name=blockMap}, tryCount=250, tryPauseMillis=500, invokeCount=11, callTimeoutMillis=100, firstInvocationTimeMs=1494828704189, firstInvocationTime='2017-05-15 11:41:44.189', lastHeartbeatMillis=0, lastHeartbeatTime='1970-01-01 05:30:00.000', target=[192.168.2.204]:5701, pendingResponse={VOID}, backupsAcksExpected=0, backupsAcksReceived=0, connection=null}
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.newOperationTimeoutException(InvocationFuture.java:151)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolve(InvocationFuture.java:99)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolveAndThrowIfException(InvocationFuture.java:75)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.get(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:155)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvokeOnPartitions.retryFailedPartitions(InvokeOnPartitions.java:143)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvokeOnPartitions.invoke(InvokeOnPartitions.java:73)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationServiceImpl.invokeOnAllPartitions(OperationServiceImpl.java:371)
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxySupport.size(MapProxySupport.java:628)
at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.size(MapProxyImpl.java:102)
at it.XXXX.tbx.server.MapLoader.run(MapLoader.java:36)
```

Regards,
Tharinda

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are trying to control waiting on the result of e.g. a map.get; you could have a look at the asynchronous version like map.getAsync. It returns a future and you can control how long you want to wait for a result.

Modifying the call timeout is not advised.

Comment: How about if can't control the `IMap.get` call, e.g. if we're using the `IMapRegionCache` from the Hibernate5 integration?